# Index on Multiple fields

Tags: microsoft-excel

```
Eff Date /  Exp Date /   Exp Comm  /   AMS Plan ID
12/01/2014   11/30/2015    205.40       SUSQU02-7001
12/01/2015   11/30/2016    305.18       SUSQU02-7001
```

I have another spreadsheet that has the AMS Plan ID and a comm payment date or

```
Eff Date /  AMS Plan ID
03/01/2016   SUSQU02-7001
```

How can I find out the expected commission from the first sheet by first matching the AMS Plan ID and then the appropriate row where the current commission date falls between? In this case the answer would be $305.18, because, although it's the same group, the expected commission falls between the second range of dates. Greatly appreciate any help you might be able to provide.

Comment: You can make a helper column in each sheet, where you concatenate the values together. Then you can VLOOKUP in that column. Not elegant, but works.

Answer (score 0):

you could do it with sumifs like this: (asuming the first table is sheet1 and the second sheet2, and there is always just one item to match)

```
=SUMIFS(Sheet1!C:C,Sheet1!A:A,"<"&Sheet2!A2,Sheet1!B:B,">"&Sheet2!A2,Sheet1!D:D,Sheet2!B2)
```